# Data studio community visualization prod deployment not reloading

Tags: looker-studio

I tried deploying a prod community visualization to my data studio report.
The problem is that I keep on changing stuff locally and these changes don't reflect after "build" and "push:prod" steps.
I try doing the same with the dev deployment and I get no errors. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, according to documentation on [Writing your visualization](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/write-viz?hl=it) and [Improving performance](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/caching?hl=it) it takes around 12h for the copy stored in caché (I guess in Google's servers) to update with any changes you made.

So it's a good idea to only use `prod` when things are working neatly.